# How can I have 2 generics use the same T type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, router

Imagine I have a view controller factory with the following type:

```swift
protocol ViewFactoryType {
  associatedtype T
  func create(for scene: T) -> UIViewController
}

final class ViewFactory<T>: ViewFactoryType {
  func create(for scene: T) -> UIViewController {
    return .init()
  }
}
```

And I also have an navigation router with the following type:

```swift
protocol RouterType {
  associatedtype T
  func navigate(to target: T, using transition: Transition)
}
```

What I would like to do is create an instance of `RouterType` and pass it and instance of a `ViewFactory`.

Both generic `T` types will in fact use the same `Scene` type.

I have tried to create that router as follows:

```swift
final class AppRouter<T>: RouterType {

  private let viewControllerFactory: ViewFactoryType
  private let navigationController: UINavigationController

  public init(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewControllerFactory: ViewFactoryType) {
    self.navigationController = navigationController
    self.viewControllerFactory = viewControllerFactory
  }

  public func navigate(to target: T, using transition: Transition) {
    routeTo(viewControllerFactory.create(for: target), transition: transition)
  }

  private func routeTo(_ viewController: UIViewController, transition: Transition) {
    switch transition {
    case .push: navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    case .present: navigationController.present(viewController, animated: true)
    case .replace: navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
    }
  }
}
```

However this produces the error:

```
Protocol 'ViewFactoryType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

and

```
Member 'create' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'ViewFactoryType'; use a generic constraint instead
```

I was able to get around this slightly by using an extension:

```swift
final class AppRouter<T> {

  private let viewControllerFactory: ViewFactoryType
  private let navigationController: UINavigationController

  public init(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewControllerFactory: ViewFactoryType) {
    self.navigationController = navigationController
    self.viewControllerFactory = viewControllerFactory
  }

  private func routeTo(_ viewController: UIViewController, transition: Transition) {
    switch transition {
    case .push: navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    case .present: navigationController.present(viewController, animated: true)
    case .replace: navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
    }
  }
}

extension AppRouter: Router where T == Scene {
  func route(to target: Scene, as transition: Transition) {

  }
}
```

But the factory method does not have the correct type if I add it too `func route(to target: Scene, as transition: Transition)`

Comment: An `associatedtype` is not a generic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, could you expand please?

Comment: imo the whole use of generics here is unnecessary. You *know* that you want to deal with view controllers here, so what's the point of having `T`? what else are you trying to accept as argument?

Comment: I may have `ChildViewControllerFactory` or a `LoggedOutViewControllerFactory` etc. What I'm trying to avoid is a single huge factory. If I want to unit test the router, I don't want to stub all the views in that factory.

Comment: @HarryBlue still, not talking about factory. You have function `func navigate(to target: T`, which means T is at the minimum `UIView`, or likely `UIViewController`. It cannot be String, or Date or any random type. So why complicate code with generics, when you can use a proper type: `protocol RouterType {
  func navigate(to target: UIViewController, using transition: Transition)
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the `associatedtype` properties in that fashion. The compiler does not understand how they should relate or how you expect them to be used.

You could refactor your `AppRouter` to accept a type that represents the `ViewFactoryType` it should expect.

```swift
final class AppRouter<T, R> {

  private let viewControllerFactory: R
  private let navigationController: UINavigationController

  public init(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewControllerFactory: R) {
    self.navigationController = navigationController
    self.viewControllerFactory = viewControllerFactory
  }

  private func routeTo(_ viewController: UIViewController, transition: Transition) {
    switch transition {
    case .push: navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    case .present: navigationController.present(viewController, animated: true)
    case .replace: navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
    }
  }
}

extension AppRouter: RouterType where T == Scene, R == ViewFactory<T> {
  func navigate(to target: Scene, as transition: Transition) {
    let viewController = viewControllerFactory.create(for: target)
    routeTo(viewController, transition: transition)
  }
}
```

You can create an instance by passing the correct type now

```swift
    let viewControllerFactory = ViewFactory<Scene>()
    let router = AppRouter<Scene, ViewFactory<Scene>>(navigationController: navigationController, viewControllerFactory: viewControllerFactory)
```

Comment: *disclaimer - I have not run that answer, however providing your code is sound, it should work,